# Unique vertices with Frames

Tags: tinkerpop

Is there a thread safe way to ensure unique vertices are created by a framed graph? Consider the following:

```java
Node n = framedGraph.addVertex(1, Node.class);
Node m = framedGraph.addVertex(1, Node.class);
System.out.println(n.equals(framedGraph.getVertex(1, Node.class)));
System.out.println(m.equals(framedGraph.getVertex(1, Node.class)));
```

prints `true, false`.

I'm looking for functionality similar to the [get or create unique node](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-unique-nodes.html#tutorials-java-embedded-unique-get-or-create) functionality provided by Neo4j (which is the backing graph in this case).

As an aside - is there a way to use non-numeric ids?

```
Node m = framedGraph.addVertex("http://example.org", Node.class);
System.out.println(n.equals(framedGraph.getVertex("http://example.org", Node.class)));
```

prints `false`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neo4j and most Graph implementations of Blueprints ignore the ID parameter.  Aside from TinkerGraph, they generally all assign their own IDs without methods to create your own.  You could always use [IdGraph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Id-Implementation) to help simulate your own ID.

Blueprints doesn't maintain the notion of "get or create".  You have to implement that yourself or I suppose it's possible to reach down into Neo4j code to do it, with the expectation that your code is no longer portable from one graph to another.  In that way, perhaps you could build a graph wrapper implementation similar to `IdGraph` that exposed a `getOrCreate()` method.  At least that way, you still get to work with the `Graph` interface and the such logic is encapsulated within that.  Of course, that won't help with enabling such functionality directly in Frames.

Comment: Thanks! This resolves the ID issue. But now when adding a vertex to the framed graph and then adding that vertex to my manually created index (`index.put("term", "foo1", n.asVertex());`) I get an exception: `com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.wrappers.id.IdVertex cannot be cast to com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.neo4j.Neo4jElement`. Any way to resolve that?

Comment: I guess you have to unwrap the `IdVertex`. Try to to take the `IdVertex` instance and call `getBaseVertex` prior to passing it to the index.  http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.4.0/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/util/wrappers/id/IdVertex.html#getBaseVertex()

Comment: Yep - `((IdVertex)n.asVertex()).getBaseVertex()` does the trick. Thanks much.